# How to determine if a (combo box) item is selected vs manually typed data?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I'm making an internal app (LEMP stack) for taking orders for tickets for regularly scheduled events. Many customers buy tix on a regular basis so...

I want to populate a combo box (datalist - for the phone number field) with the results of a mysql query that uses an inner join to get the customer name and phone number (from the customers table) along with the type(s) of credit card, the last 4 digits of the card number, and the expiration date. I plan to use a type-ahead function to automatically display and filter results as the phone number is typed.

In use, it would look like this:

SCENARIO A:

1. User begins typing a phone number.
2. At the 7th digit, there are 3 entries in the list - one for Bob Jones and 2 for Tom Smith (because Tom has used 2 different credit cards to purchase tickets in the past.)
3. User confirms she is speaking to Tom Smith and asks whether he want to use the Master Card ending in 6789 or the Visa ending in 1234.
4. Tom wants to use the Visa, so the user clicks that list item (or arrows down 'til it's selected then hits tab)
5. The Customer Name, Credit Card Number, and CC Expiration Date are filled in automatically and the list box for selecting which event gets the focus.

SCENARIO B:

1. The user types in the first 6+ numbers and there are no list items because the phone number provided is not in the database.
2. The user clicks on or tabs to the Customer Name field and manually enters the remaining data.

When the user submits the form, Scenario B will need to insert the customer's name into the Customers table, the customers phone number (and the customer ID) into the PhoneNumbers table, the credit card type, number, and exp. date (and the customer ID) into the CreditCards table, then insert the ticket details (which will include the EventID and CustomerID) into the Tickets table.

In Scenario A, though, only the ticket details will need to be inserted because the customer, phone number, and credit card info are all in the database already.

[Edited for clarity - hopefully]

Comment: I suspect you may be overthinking this. Is there any reason you can't just check after submission to see if the number exists in the customer table?

Comment: But I'm trying to populate the Customer Name, Credit Card Type, Credit Card Number, and CC Exp. Date fields on the form - based on the phone number - all before submitting the form...?

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your question to improve clarity? I was responding specifically to the following paragraph: `The part that has me perplexed is that once the form is submitted... Path 2 will need to do an insert query to put the customer's name and phone number into the customers table, and insert the credit card info into the cards table THEN insert the ticket info into the tickets table. Whereas Path 1 will only need to insert the ticket info into the tickets table.`

Comment: Done. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What if they select one and then edit the number? I would say always run a query after submission to see if you need to create or update anything.

Comment: I have no problem with running a query after submission to see if I need to create or update anything but what I’m trying to do here is populate additional fields on the form - before the form is submitted - based on the phone number entered/list item selected. If they go back and change the number, then the type-ahead should kick in and show list items that match.

Comment: What have you tried? What specific problem are you struggling with? Many jurisdictions have data protection regulations that require multiple pieces of information to identify an account holder. Searching on a partial telephone number would not satisfy these requirements. Storing card data is most likely a breach of your merchant account agreement and would require PCI DSS Level 1 certification, something you probably want to avoid.